# Visual Studio Code - saving js and scss with version number

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, gruntjs

is there any preference to be configured in Visual Studio Code in order to have scss compiled with a version number?  Same thing for js?

What I mean is having somehitng like  globalstyle.63c1c17c.css or something like that, in order to keep track of the versions.

I have read something about Grunt or Gulp, but I have no idea how to use them, so far. I'll try to read something about, but in the meanwhile, do you guys have any suggestion?

Thank you